# AS3 Textfield Can't Select Color with ColorPicker on only Selected Text

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, textfield, color-picker

I'm creating a text editor and I want users to be able to select only part of a textfield and change the color.  The problem I'm running into is the ColorPicker gains focus (I'm guessing) and the textfield loses it's "selection."

All examples of text editing show the entire textfield changing color.  Which isn't exactly what I want.

Any help/insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out what it is that causes your text field selection to be lost (e.g. could it be the click on the color picker component?). Then get the `selectionBeginIndex` and `selectionEndIndex` from the text field before that happens, and store it in a persistant (e.g. class member) variable.

When the user selects a color, use the `setTextFormat()` to change the color, passing in the stored start and end indices.

A quick example:

```
var beginIndex : uint;
var endIndex : uint;

function beforeFocusIsLost() : void {
    beginIndex = myTextField.selectionBeginIndex;
    endIndex = myTextField.selectionEndIndex;
}

function whenColorIsPicked() : void {
    var tf : TextFormat;

    tf = new TextFormat();
    tf.color = myColor;

    myTextField.setTextFormat(tf, beginIndex, endIndex);
}
```

If you want to keep the selection, you can also reset it after the color has been set using the [TextField.setSelection()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#setSelection%28%29) method.

EDIT: Note that if the selection is just hidden, maybe what you're after is simply [TextField.alwaysShowSelection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#alwaysShowSelection). Try setting it to true on your text field, and all of the above may be redundant.

```
myTextField.alwaysShowSelection = true;
```

Comment: Ok, that works.  And that's the direction I was headed.  I need the textfield to appear to still have the same text selected.  I believe that the ColorPicker is taking focus and that's why the TextField text no longer appears to be selected.  So what i'm testing now is calling TextField.setSelection() on ColorPicker.open() and close().  Thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, seems to make sense. If the selection is not really lost, but only hidden, you might be able to just use myTextField.alwaysShowSelection = true;